# MySQL Queries using Doctrine & CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, doctrine

EDIT: The reason why my Doctrine queries (see below) did not work/produced those errors was because I left out

> ci_doctrine.

when creating this database:

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_doctrine`.`user` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `username` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    `password` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    `first_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    `last_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    UNIQUE (`username`
)
)
```

END OF EDIT

How do I write plane SQL queries using Doctrine connection object and display the results? For example, how do I perform:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%anything_similar_to_this%';
```

using Doctrine something like this (this example does not work)

```
 $search_key = 'search_for_this';

 $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();

 $conn->execute('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE ?)',  $search_key);

 echo $conn;
```

I've also tried:

```
$search_key = 2;
$q = new Doctrine_RawSql();
$result = $q->select('column_name')
  ->from('table_name')
  ->where('id = ?', $search_key)
  ->execute();

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine uses It's own query language called DQL. And it uses a query class to handle the queries called Doctrine_Query. Through this class you can build a query using the so called query builder.

You can look at the documentation at http://doctrine-project.com to find out how it works exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary parenthesis which is probably causing an error. Try changing:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE ?)
```

to:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE ?
```

If it still doesn't work, try posting the error message.

Comment: +1. I changed: $conn->execute('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE ?)', $search_key); to $conn->execute('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE ?', $search_key); and got the following error: Severity: 4096 Message: Argument 2 passed to Doctrine_Connection::execute() must be an array, string given, call in... Severity: Warning Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()... Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in...